Replace with inplace=True on filtering dataframe
i have dictionary with column name to_replace and replace_value
d_numerical_approved={'no_of_dependents': {nan, 2.5}, 'income_annum': {nan, 5000000.0}, 'loan_amount': {nan, 14600000.0}, 'loan_term': {nan, 10.0}, 'cibil_score': {nan, 711.0}, 'residential_assets_value': {nan, 5400000.0}, 'commercial_assets_value': {nan, 3700000.0}, 'luxury_assets_value': {nan, 14400000.0}, 'bank_asset_value': {nan, 4500000.0}}

df.loc[df.loc[:,"loan_status"]==" Approved"].replace(d_numerical_approved,inplace=True)

when trying to replace on filtered dataframe it is throwing error
when i am tring on whole dataframe it is working on filtered dataframe also it is working but when inplace-True it is throwing below error.
Error:-
<ipython-input-114-989a23c056cc>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df.loc[df.loc[:,"loan_status"]==" Approved"].replace(d_numerical_approved,inplace=True)
<ipython-input-114-989a23c056cc>:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df.loc[df.loc[:,"loan_status"]==" Approved"].replace(d_numerical_approved,inplace=True)

Error in replace with inplace=True parameter


Don't mix loc indexing and inplace=True. Rather use a mask m = df.loc[:,"loan_status"]==" Approved" ; df[m] = df['m].replace(d_numerical_approved)
